# выравнивание блока в родительском?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не получается выровнять блок  по центру родительского

```css
.footer{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 350px;
  background-color:black;
  max-height: 450px;
}
.footer_column{

  position: absolute;
  flex-basis: 711px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}
div{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
<div class="footer_column"></div>
    </footer>
```

Нужно что бы блок footer_column отступал от верхнего края footer на 60рх (получилось )  и что бы отступы слева и справа были одинаковые (не получилось ) . какую команду использовать ?

Comment: желтую линию в 60рх я смог задать а зеленые не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас просто мешанина в коде. Вы и `flexbox` запихнули, а потом просто убрали `footer_column` из потока документа путем `position: absolute`.

```css
.footer{
  display: flex;
  min-height: 350px;
  background-color: black;
  max-height: 450px;
}

.footer_column{
  margin: 60px auto 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 250px;
}

div{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="footer_column"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Я только начал изучать и пока не совсем понимаю. Можно ли по подробней рассказать  , или  код  подправить , для дальнейшего изучения

Comment: рабочий код я скинул. Объяснения вы найдете на mdn про [поток](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA) и [блочную модель](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box_model).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ